# How to get number of rows inserted by a transaction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have to manage a log where i have to see the number of rows that are inserted by a transaction. Is there any way of doing it dynamically ?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

@@ROWCOUNT will give the number of rows affected by the **last** SQL statement, it is best to capture it into a local variable following the command in question, as its value will change the next time you look at it:

```
DECLARE @Rows int
DECLARE @TestTable table (col1 int, col2 int)
INSERT INTO @TestTable (col1, col2) select 1,2 union select 3,4
SELECT @Rows=@@ROWCOUNT
SELECT @Rows AS Rows,@@ROWCOUNT AS [ROWCOUNT]
```

OUTPUT:

```
(2 row(s) affected)
Rows        ROWCOUNT
----------- -----------
2           1

(1 row(s) affected)
```

you get `Rows` value of 2, the number of inserted rows, but ROWCOUNT is 1 because the `SELECT @Rows=@@ROWCOUNT` command affected 1 row

if you have multiple INSERTs or UPDATEs, etc. in your transaction, you need to determine how you would like to "count" what is going on. You could have a separate total for each table, a single grand total value, or something completely different.  You'll need to DECLARE a variable for each total you want to track and add to it following each operation that applies to it:

```
--note there is no error handling here, as this is a simple example
DECLARE @AppleTotal  int
DECLARE @PeachTotal  int

SELECT @AppleTotal=0,@PeachTotal=0

BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO Apple (col1, col2) Select col1,col2 from xyz where ...
SET @AppleTotal=@AppleTotal+@@ROWCOUNT

INSERT INTO Apple (col1, col2) Select col1,col2 from abc where ...
SET @AppleTotal=@AppleTotal+@@ROWCOUNT

INSERT INTO Peach (col1, col2) Select col1,col2 from xyz where ...
SET @PeachTotal=@PeachTotal+@@ROWCOUNT

INSERT INTO Peach (col1, col2) Select col1,col2 from abc where ...
SET @PeachTotal=@PeachTotal+@@ROWCOUNT

COMMIT

SELECT @AppleTotal AS AppleTotal, @PeachTotal AS PeachTotal
```

Comment: Instead of using `SELECT @Rows=@@ROWCOUNT`, I tried `SET @Rows=@@ROWCOUNT` and still received the same results.  Thank you, nice post!

Comment: FYI:  _Even_ wrapping my INSERT statment in Transaction block statements caused the @@RowCount to be reset, so I had to set the @Rows variable before calling Commit!

Comment: @MikeTeeVee by using `SELECT` you can make multiple assignments in a single statement, so you can easily add `SELECT @Rows=@@ROWCOUNT, @ID=SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @Error=@@ERROR`.  With `SET` you can only set one value.  `TRY CATCH` eliminate the need for capturing `@@ERROR`, but I still use `SELECT`.

Comment: @MikeTeeVee, You must capture `@@ROWCOUNT` immediately after the command you are interested in because it is set following every command, even `COMMIT`, even your `SET @Rows=@@ROWCOUNT`.  For example, if you update 4 rows and then commit, your `@@ROWCOUNT` will be 4 after the `UPDATE` but will be zero after the `COMMIT`.  That is the reason for capturing `@@ROWCOUNT` in a local variable.

Comment: I tried this method. It works great on Management studio but when i try to execute the same query in my code it always returns `0` for `rows` and `1` for `rowcount`. I am not sure if there's anywhere I am going wrong

Comment: `@@ROWCOUNT` is bad practice. For ad-hoc scripts it is fine, but for *production* scripts it is just a BUG waiting to happen. It requires only one programmer that missed the `@@ROWCOUNT` and inserted some code between the insert and the `@@ROWCOUNT`.

Answer (score 12):

In case you need further info for your log/audit you can OUTPUT clause:
This way, not only you keep the number of rows affected, but also what records.

As an example of the Output Clause during inserts:
[SQL Server list of insert identities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619343/sql-server-list-of-insert-identities)

```
DECLARE @InsertedIDs table(ID int);

INSERT INTO YourTable
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
        INTO @InsertedIDs 
    SELECT ...
```

HTH

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to may previous post. Here it is.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (id int) 

INSERT INTO @TestTable (col1, col2) OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO #TempTable select 1,2 

INSERT INTO @TestTable (col1, col2) OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO #TempTable select 3,4 

SELECT * FROM #TempTable --this select will chage @@ROWCOUNT value
```

Answer (score 0):

@@ROWCOUNT might be a way to go, although over time we tend to add more code and we might put something that may skew the numbers by using rowcount.

1. OUTPUT will show the right numbers, but will waste some space might be a little slow, and may lock the table for a longer period, depending on a number of rows inserted and lock escalation level.
2. The easiest way would be to count before and after, although not the fastest.
3. The fastest way would be using system partition tables, but it might not be as accurate as count (due to system tables update latency).

   `select t.name,sum(p.rows) FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id where i.index_id in (0,1) /* table has clustered index or index on the heap*/`

Answer (score -2):

You can use `@@trancount` in MSSQL

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/trancount-transact-sql):

> Returns the number of BEGIN TRANSACTION statements that have occurred on the current connection.