# SQL Server list of insert identities

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, insert

I have a table with an autoincrement id that I am doing a

```
INSERT INTO ( ... ) SELECT ... FROM ...
```

Is there a way for me to get the list of id's that have been inserted?

I was thinking I could get the max id before the insert then after and assuming everything in between is new, but then if a row gets inserted from somewhere else I could run into problems. Is there a proper way to do this?

I am using SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use the [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause.

```
DECLARE @InsertedIDs table(ID int);

INSERT INTO YourTable
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
        INTO @InsertedIDs 
    SELECT ...
```

Comment: Great! Wondering if there are ways to return this @InsertedIDs to C#?

Answer (score 3):

Create a `table` variable and then use the `OUTPUT` clause into the `table` variable.

`OUTPUT inserted.NameOfYourColumnId INTO tableVariable`

Then you can `SELECT` from your `table` variable.