# Identity From Multiple Inserts

Tags: sql-server

I think I already know the answer but...

Given this statement:

```
Insert Into Allergy (Name, Category, Composition)
Select Name, Category, Composition
From ETVault Where Strain In (6, 2, 4)
```

Is it possible to get the identities that were inserted?

I understand I can break this into multiple statements and capture scope_identity() after each but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server list of insert identities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619343/sql-server-list-of-insert-identities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way I thought of doing this is to use a `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` on the table,  capture the entire rowset inserted, and get the identities from there.

**EDIT** Of course, you can do this by capturing OUTPUT (doh)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Here is a working sample, Since you hadn't provided sample data, I created my own Allery and ETVault tables, so use the example in a brand new database.

```
DROP TABLE Allergy
GO
CREATE TABLE Allergy
(
ID INTEGER IDENTITY (1, 1), NAME VarChar (20), Category VarChar (20), Composition VarChar (20)
)
GO
DROP TABLE ETVault
Go
CREATE TABLE ETVault 
(
ID INTEGER IDENTITY (1, 1), Strain INT, NAME VarChar (20), Category VarChar (20), Composition VarChar (20)
)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.ETVault
        ( Strain, NAME, Category, Composition )
VALUES  
( 1, '1',  '1',  '1'),
( 2, '1',  '1',  '1'),
( 3, '1',  '1',  '1'),
( 4, '1',  '1',  '1'),
( 5, '1',  '1',  '1'),
( 6, '1',  '1',  '1'),
( 7, '1',  '1',  '1'),
( 8, '1',  '1',  '1')

DECLARE @CaptureTable TABLE (ID INT)


INSERT INTO dbo.Allergy
        ( NAME, Category, Composition )
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @CaptureTable
SELECT dbo.ETVault.NAME, Category, Composition
FROM dbo.ETVault
Where Strain In (6, 2, 4)


SELECT * FROM @CaptureTable
```

It gives you the output

```
(8 row(s) affected)

(3 row(s) affected)
ID
-----------
1
2
3

(3 row(s) affected)
```