# sql copy of identity column as a string

Tags: sql

Im creating a procedure that simply creates a copy of a row but changes some values.

In the newly created record (which is a copy of an existing record) I need one of the fields to be a string representation of the recordID (an auto-generated IDENTITY column) of the newly created record.

```
CREATE PROC sp @RecordID int
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TheTable([RecordName], ...)
    SELECT CAST(@RecordID as nvarchar(500)), ...
    FROM TheTable
    WHERE [RecordID] = @RecordID
END
```

my code is wrong because it sets the RecordName to the RecordID of the record being copied FROM. I need the RecordName to be the same as the RecordID of the record being created.

Thanks for the help

Comment: So you want a column with a character representation of its own new identity value?

Comment: So you want your table to look like: `(RecordId, RecordName): (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (4,4), ...`? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: yup. sorry if this wasnt clear

Comment: No idea why but this is what was requested. I thought to copy the ID of the record being copied from but was asked to correct it

Comment: A Trigger? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171622/get-identity-value-in-the-same-t-sql-statement-it-is-created-in

Comment: Thanks alex. That trigger is certainly a solution if it has to be done 'in one statement' but being that my logic is wrapped inside the SP, simply updating is will work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that what you describe is possible — the identity value isn't available until the statement completes — but there's a simple workaround:

```
CREATE PROC sp @RecordID int
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TheTable([RecordName], ...)
    SELECT 'temporary dummy value', ...
    FROM TheTable
    WHERE [RecordID] = @RecordID
    ;

    UPDATE TheTable
    SET [RecordName] = CAST(@@IDENTITY as nvarchar(500))
    WHERE [RecordID] = @@IDENTITY
    ;
END
```

(See [the documentation for `@@IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933167.aspx).)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'll need to do this in 2 steps - insert the new data into the table, then update the record with the new recordID

For example (assuming Sql Server),

```
declare @myNewID int    

INSERT INTO TheTable([RecordName], ...)
SELECT CAST(@RecordID as nvarchar(500)), ...
FROM TheTable
WHERE [RecordID] = @RecordID

set @myNewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

UPDATE TheTable
    set [RecordName] = CAST(@myNewID as nvarchar(500))
WHERE [RecordID] = @myNewID
```