# Is there a way to make INSTEAD OF Triggers work with SCOPE_IDENTITY?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

This trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER InsteadTrigger on CustomerView
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Person
        SELECT FirstName, LastName
        FROM inserted
```

Causes this query to return null.

```
INSERT INTO CustomerView (FirstName, LastName) Values ('Jonathan', 'Allen')
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Is there a way to fix the trigger so that SCOPE_IDENTITY will return the correct value? (I can't use @@IDENTITY because there may be other triggers on the table involved.)

Comment: P.S. My customer is asking about this. I would never intentionally get myself into this situation.

Comment: First off, your making the very common error of assuming the INSERT would only process one row. Multiple rows can be inserted by a single insert statement.

Comment: No I'm not. The trigger will work for multiple rows and no one expects SCOPE_IDENTITY to work unless you only inserted one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server list of insert identities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619343/sql-server-list-of-insert-identities)

Comment: @JoeStefanelli - That doesn't work here. I was going to suggest the `OUTPUT` clause but it always seems to return `0` in my test. It does the `OUTPUT` clause before generating the `identity` [Test script here](https://gist.github.com/1732636)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No I don't think this is possible.

You can return it from the trigger itself of course.

```
ALTER TRIGGER InsteadTrigger on CustomerView
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Person
        SELECT FirstName, LastName
        FROM inserted

        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS PersonId
END
```

And you can use `CONTEXT_INFO` to suppress the result set except for when you require it.

Using  the `OUTPUT` clause doesn't work in this context as discussed in [this Microsoft Connect Item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/427666/instead-trigger-return-zero-number-into-output-identity) it is evaluated before the insert into the main table and so before the `IDENTITY` function is called.

Comment: Not great, but then again neither is this whole situation. At this time I do believe this is the best that they can hope for.