# How many rows inserted into table by create table statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, create-table

Is there a way to count how many rows inserted into table by

```
Create table tbl1 as select * from tbl2;
```

statement which performed from PL\SQL function (execute immediate)?

When I'm using SQL%ROWCOUNT the result is 1.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get number of rows inserted by a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272733/how-to-get-number-of-rows-inserted-by-a-transaction)

Comment: I'm searching for a solution in Oracle not Sql server

Comment: `SQL%ROWCOUNT` will give the number of rows afftected by DML statement, When you executed `Execute immediate <yoursql>`, there was only 1 operation happened and inthat table is created so rowcount you are getting as 1. In the next step you can count it. in a variable and check it,

Comment: Yes, I guess that that why I'm getting 1. What you mean "In the next step you can count it. in a variable and check it" ? select count(*) from tbl1?

Comment: @user2671057 You can see my answer what i meant to say.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. As mentioned in my comment you need to do it as followed. Remember that you need again to use `Execute immediate` else you get an issue that tab1 is undefined.

```
DECLARE
   vsql   VARCHAR2 (200);

   cnt    NUMBER;
BEGIN
   vsql := 'create table tbl1 as select * from employee';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vsql;

   vsql := 'select count(1) from tbl1';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vsql INTO cnt;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (cnt);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing. You can first create an empty table `tbl1` from `tbl2`. Then insert data using `SELECT` and then use- `SQL%ROWCOUNT`.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 AS SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE 1=2;
INSERT INTO tbl1 SELECT * FROM tbl2;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('No. of rows inserted in TBL2 from TBL1 = ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
```